# When I try to use a file storage (Azure) to upload a pdf in Laravel, I get an error 409

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-storage, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to use **Laravel file storage** to upload a pdf that I create in the code just moments before, however, when I'm trying to upload it, I receive an **Azure error 409** that states: *'The specified resource type does not match the type of the existing resource.'*, here is my code:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('emails.boleta-liquidado', ['op' => $op])->setOrientation('landscape');
Storage::put('primario/Cooperativas', $pdf->output());
```

Comment: 409 (conflict), means that the file is already there (it's already uploaded). Try specifying a different name or delete the existing one before upload

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio the thing is that the storage account is empty, I create a new one for this project.

Comment: @Charlie Hi, Charlie. Can you post the comment above as the answer to end this question? :)